# Test.loadData with sObject Throws Unknown field: Exception

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-data-isolation

Iam loading a CSV file via Static Resourced to test my APEX code. I am using the following code in my test:

```
  List<sObject> ls1 = Test.loadData(Account.sObjectType, 'TestAccount');
```

CSV file look like below:

```
    FirstName,LastName,PersonEmail 
    TestName1,TestName12,test@name1.com 
    TestName2,TestName22,test@name2.com
```

I am getting the following error:

```
System.SObjectException: Business Account may not use Person Account field PersonEmail
```

I want to load person account test data. For this, how can i use/assign personAccount record type in csv file to overcome this exception.

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried adding the RecordTypeId of PersonAccount record type?

Comment: The error could also persist due to PersonEmail field as it is exist on Contact object. If this is the case, then remove the PersonEmail field and once the insert is done, perform an update operation with PersonEmail fields.

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
FirstName,LastName,PersonEmail, RecordTypeId
TestName1,TestName12,test@name1.com, 012E00000000iEyAsI
TestName2,TestName22,test@name2.com, 012E00000000iEyAsI
```

Assign person type record type to insert a person Account. Otherwise record is treated as business account.

As you are static resource, you may not have scope to set recordtype id dynamically. Hardcoding will work in single instance only.

Comment: @Ashwani- But we need to do without hardcoding Id's in file or apex code. Is there any way?